# How to increase upload size WordPress xampp

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I have already changed the upload file size, Max upload side and Max execution time in my C:/xampp/php/php.ini. Also form other forums I used the @ini_set code in my functions.php. I even edited my '.htaccess' but still my Max upload size is still 1MB. Please is there any other solution? I have tried everything on this website http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/

I even set xampp to run as administrator, still nothing. Please any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: In my php info, it shows 64M from the code I got from that link, but I am still restricted to 1MB

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it, all those methods never worked beacuase my xampp was on multi site, I just manage to revert it back to single site and the post upload size has increased successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In **PHP.ini** file add

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 25M
memory_limit = 30M
```

Also edit .htaccess file and add

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20MB
php_value post_max_size 25MB
php_value memory_limit 30MB
```

Another method is to modify the WordPress file wp-config.php or functions.php files, and paste the following lines of code

```
@ini_set( ‘upload_max_size’ , ’20MB’ );
@ini_set( ‘post_max_size’, ’25MB’);
@ini_set( ‘memory_limit’, ’30MB’ );
```

If you still having an issue then [check](https://www.wpblog.com/wordpress-maximum-upload-file-size/)  here you can easily learn **how to increase upload size limit?**

Answer (score 0):

Edit `function.php`

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

or edit `htaccess`

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```